# c++ forward referencing

Tags: c++

I know this is probably really stupid but how does one do forward reference of inherited classes

Like

```
class parent
{
...stuff in here
}


class child1 : public parent
{
....
}

class child2 : public parent
{
....
}
```

All the classes have to be in the same file and I'm using instances of child2 inside child1 and vice verse. How do I do the forward referencing here? If I just say

```
class child2;
```

at the beginning of the code the compiler does not recognize that it is a subclass of parent when I use it in child1 (and hence the virtual functions don't work). Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "using instances of child2?"  If you mean actual objects, you can't do this with forward declarations.  You can only use pointers and references.

Comment: @Maxpm: He can use instances in the function body, if he stops writing the function body inline in the class definition. :) Indeed, forward declarations only give him pointer/reference usage -- possibly useful here in function declarations.

Answer (score 1):

Adding up all of the advice into one compilable example, we have:

```
#include <iostream>


class parent {
private:
  int m_baseData;
public:
  parent(int myData) : m_baseData(myData) {}
  int GetData() { return m_baseData; }
};

class child2;

class child1 : public parent {
private:
  child2 *m_pChild2;
public:
  int GetSiblingData(); /* { return m_pChild2->m_baseData; } */
  child1(int myData, child2& c2) : parent(myData), m_pChild2(&c2) {}
};

class child2 : public parent {
public:
  child2(int myData) : parent(myData) {}
};

inline
int child1::GetSiblingData() {
  return m_pChild2->GetData();
}


int main() {
  child2 c2(56);
  child1 c1(42, c2);
  std::cout << c1.GetSiblingData() << "\n";
}
```

Please note several things:

- First, the forward declaration of `class2`. This declares an incomplete type. Incomplete types may be used in pointers and references, but those pointers may not be dereferenced unless the complete type is declared.
- Next, notice that I did not include the function body for `child1::GetSiblingData()` in the `child1` class definition. This is because `child2` is still an incomplete type. As you correctly observed, the compile does not yet know what inheritance of `child2` is yet.
- Note that the definition of `child2` may occur even when a previous forward declaration of `child2` exists. This definition means that `child2` is no longer an incomplete type.
- Finally, notice that definition of `child1::GetSiblingData` follows the definition of both `child1` and `child2`. By this point in the program, `child2` is no longer incomplete, so you can mention its members.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
class child1
{
    ...
    class child2 *c;
    ...
};

class child2
{
    ...
    class child1 *c;
    ...
};
```

Comment: More about forward declarations and its usage you can read in [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.11)

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about forward declarations, not forward references.

> All the classes have to be in the same
>   file and I'm using instances of child2
>   inside child1 and vice verse. How do I
>   do the forward referencing here? If I
>   just say
>
> ```
> class child2;
> ```
>
> at the beginning of the code the
>   compiler does not recognize that it is
>   a subclass of parent when I use it in
>   child1 (and hence the virtual
>   functions don't work). Please help.

You can't "use" it at all through a forward declaration. Use the forward declaration as you suggest:

```
class child2;
```

so that you can declare functions the classes, then define the function bodies in some .cpp file.